# Localize attribute parameters in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a simple ASP.NET Core API and I have already done the basic localization setup in Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
    };

    var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);

    // . . .
}
```

Which works just fine. Let's say we have the following controller:

```cs
public class CarsController
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<CarsController> localizer;

    public CarsController(IStringLocalizer<CarsController> localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Some Summary", Description = "Some Description")]
    public IActionResult test()
    {
        var result = this.localizer["TEST"];
        return Ok(result.Value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The issue I'm facing here is with the SwaggerOperationAttribute (which is for auto-generating of a swagger for the API). Is it possible to localize those strings that are the parameters of this attribute?